# PHP Array how to group the children an alphanumeric array block

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is a follow up question to one thankfully answered by users.

In the following array I have parent strings with a block of nested child strings.  What I'm trying to do it create a new array from this one where the alphanumeric child string keys are grouped by their appended numbers.  I also have a problem with the order of the child keys as it goes 'title, desc, price, image then for some reason reverses and then goes back to the original order on the third child loop.

Heres what I have so far :

```
[
    {
        "hair-and-beauty": {
            "_business_title_0": "service 1",
            "_business_description_0": "service 1",
            "_business_price_0": "22",
            "_business_image_id_0": "2367",
            "_business_price_1": "66",
            "_business_image_id_1": "2367",
            "_business_title_1": "service 2",
            "_business_description_1": "service 2",
            "_business_title_2": "service 3",
            "_business_description_2": "service 3",
            "_business_price_2": "33",
            "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
        }
    },
    {
        "hair-colouring": {
            "_business_title_0": "service 1",
            "_business_description_0": "service 1",
            "_business_price_0": "22",
            "_business_image_id_0": "2367",
            "_business_price_1": "66",
            "_business_image_id_1": "2367",
            "_business_title_1": "service 2",
            "_business_description_1": "service 2",
            "_business_title_2": "service 3",
            "_business_description_2": "service 3",
            "_business_price_2": "33",
            "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
        }
    }
]
```

By amending the original mysql I managed to group them in order using a cast statement however I'm now trying to traverse over the array and use a preg_replace to strip the numbers and use them as an int to order them into groups.

What I need is this structure.

```
[
    {
        "hair-and-beauty": {
          { 
            "_business_title_0": "service 1",
            "_business_description_0": "service 1",
            "_business_price_0": "22",
            "_business_image_id_0": "2367",
          },
          {
            "_business_title_1": "66",            //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
            "_business_description_1": "2367",    //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
            "_business_price_1": "service 2",     //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
            "_business_images_id_1": "service 2", //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
           },
           {
            "_business_title_2": "service 3",
            "_business_description_2": "service 3",
            "_business_price_2": "33",
            "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
           }
        }
    },
    {
        "hair-colouring": {
           {
            "_business_title_0": "service 1",
            "_business_description_0": "service 1",
            "_business_price_0": "22",
            "_business_image_id_0": "2367"
           }
            "_business_title_1": "66",          //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
            "_business_description_1": "2367",  //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
            "_business_price_1": "service 2",   //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
            "_business_image_id_1": "service 2" //Correctly ordered 2nd loop
           },
           {
            "_business_title_2": "service 3",
            "_business_description_2": "service 3",
            "_business_price_2": "33",
            "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
           }
        }
    }
]
```

I used a similar loop on an array for a different page which loops through and reorders the array but I'm hitting a wall on this one and I'm at the point of redoing it all and changing the way the frontend inputs, database stores and then this page outputs which feels like 10 steps back.  If you could help by pointing me in the right direction / correct php array function to use to achieve this it would help me out a lot.

The code I did for the other function I'm now trying to unsuccessfully alter is as follows:

```
        foreach($info5 as $row){
            $int = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $row["meta_key"]);
            $items[$int][$row["meta_key"]] = $row["meta_value"];
            if(strpos('_menu_cat_', $row["meta_key"]) === true){
                $menu[$row["meta_value"]] = array();
            }
        }
```

The problem with the above is that I need all the children to be present on each parent as the parents are categories and the children can be in multiple.  Upon insertion into the database using a form you select multiple categories from a dropdown and then fill out the product information.  The issue it that the database doesn't have a category ID in the table the entry is listed in and adding the additional column is problematic for preexisting pages which count columns etc.  It's not how I would have set it up but it's what I have to work with.
The above will only find the children for the first category then the sequential parent categories don't have any child strings so they are null.  I need to kind of fake the result to use the same children for all parents, hence why I'm trying to fudge the result by altering the final array I've posted above.  I hope I'm not being too unhelpful in the description.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code for your manipulating with your array:

```
$json = '[
    {
        "hair-and-beauty": {
            "_business_title_0": "service 1",
            "_business_description_0": "service 1",
            "_business_price_0": "22",
            "_business_image_id_0": "2367",
            "_business_price_1": "66",
            "_business_image_id_1": "2367",
            "_business_title_1": "service 2",
            "_business_description_1": "service 2",
            "_business_title_2": "service 3",
            "_business_description_2": "service 3",
            "_business_price_2": "33",
            "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
        }
    },
    {
        "hair-colouring": {
            "_business_title_0": "service 1",
            "_business_description_0": "service 1",
            "_business_price_0": "22",
            "_business_image_id_0": "2367",
            "_business_price_1": "66",
            "_business_image_id_1": "2367",
            "_business_title_1": "service 2",
            "_business_description_1": "service 2",
            "_business_title_2": "service 3",
            "_business_description_2": "service 3",
            "_business_price_2": "33",
            "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
        }
    }
]';

$resultArray = [];
$arrayFromJson = json_decode($json, 1);

foreach ($arrayFromJson as $ind => $group) {
  foreach ($group as $key => $array) {
    asort($array);
    foreach ($array as $arrayKey => $value) {
      preg_match('/^_.*_(\d+)$/', $arrayKey, $match);
      $resultArray[$ind][$key][$match[1]][$arrayKey] = $value;
    }
  }
}

echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And result:

```
[
    {
        "hair-and-beauty": [
            {
                "_business_title_0": "service 1",
                "_business_description_0": "service 1",
                "_business_price_0": "22",
                "_business_image_id_0": "2367"
            },
            {
                "_business_price_1": "66",
                "_business_image_id_1": "2367",
                "_business_title_1": "service 2",
                "_business_description_1": "service 2"
            },
            {
                "_business_title_2": "service 3",
                "_business_description_2": "service 3",
                "_business_price_2": "33",
                "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "hair-colouring": [
            {
                "_business_title_0": "service 1",
                "_business_description_0": "service 1",
                "_business_price_0": "22",
                "_business_image_id_0": "2367"
            },
            {
                "_business_price_1": "66",
                "_business_image_id_1": "2367",
                "_business_title_1": "service 2",
                "_business_description_1": "service 2"
            },
            {
                "_business_title_2": "service 3",
                "_business_description_2": "service 3",
                "_business_price_2": "33",
                "_business_image_id_2": "2367"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: That's fantastic and has saved me so much time, appreciated.

Comment: @Diego no problem)

Comment: Although the second child loop is still organised incorrectly.  Do you know there's something I could add to sort that?

Comment: in the first child it's : title, desc, price, image and then the second child is reversed, then the third, title, desc, price, image again.

Comment: I don't mind which order they are in tbh I just need the child strings in the same order to parse in my c# code you see.

Comment: Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

Please see this code, it will give you the end result

```
<?php
$array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'hair-and-beauty' => 
    array (
      '_business_title_0' => 'service 1',
      '_business_description_0' => 'service 1',
      '_business_price_0' => '22',
      '_business_image_id_0' => '2367',
      '_business_price_1' => '66',
      '_business_image_id_1' => '2367',
      '_business_title_1' => 'service 2',
      '_business_description_1' => 'service 2',
      '_business_title_2' => 'service 3',
      '_business_description_2' => 'service 3',
      '_business_price_2' => '33',
      '_business_image_id_2' => '2367',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'hair-colouring' => 
    array (
      '_business_title_0' => 'service 1',
      '_business_description_0' => 'service 1',
      '_business_price_0' => '22',
      '_business_image_id_0' => '2367',
      '_business_price_1' => '66',
      '_business_image_id_1' => '2367',
      '_business_title_1' => 'service 2',
      '_business_description_1' => 'service 2',
      '_business_title_2' => 'service 3',
      '_business_description_2' => 'service 3',
      '_business_price_2' => '33',
      '_business_image_id_2' => '2367',
    ),
  ),
);
echo '<pre>';
print_R($array);
$finalResult = [];
foreach($array as $key => $level1) {
    foreach($level1 as $level2_key => $level2) {
        foreach($level2 as $level3_key => $level3) {
            $lastchar = substr($level3_key, -1);
            $finalResult[$level2_key][$lastchar][$level3_key] = $level3;
        }
    }
}
print_R($finalResult);
?>
```

Final result:

```
Array
(
    [hair-and-beauty] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_business_title_0] => service 1
                    [_business_description_0] => service 1
                    [_business_price_0] => 22
                    [_business_image_id_0] => 2367
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_business_price_1] => 66
                    [_business_image_id_1] => 2367
                    [_business_title_1] => service 2
                    [_business_description_1] => service 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [_business_title_2] => service 3
                    [_business_description_2] => service 3
                    [_business_price_2] => 33
                    [_business_image_id_2] => 2367
                )

        )

    [hair-colouring] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_business_title_0] => service 1
                    [_business_description_0] => service 1
                    [_business_price_0] => 22
                    [_business_image_id_0] => 2367
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_business_price_1] => 66
                    [_business_image_id_1] => 2367
                    [_business_title_1] => service 2
                    [_business_description_1] => service 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [_business_title_2] => service 3
                    [_business_description_2] => service 3
                    [_business_price_2] => 33
                    [_business_image_id_2] => 2367
                )

        )

)
```